# Are cropped hashes harder to crack?

Tags: php, security, authentication, hash, md5

Cropping a hash should mean losing some of the data it represents so I was wondering if cropped hashes are harder to crack and more specifically if storing cropped password hashes for user authentication is an idea worth examining.

Comment: How would you check a password against the cropped hash??? crop the hashed password too? That would mean there is more chance of collisions. So: BAD BAD idea!

Comment: @PeeHaa, hash, crop and compare.

Comment: Seems to me that all you would do is increase the chances of collisions.

Comment: Why are you cropping a hash?  That is horrible idea.  All that's doing is increasing the changes of a hash collision.  Also, you cannot "decrypt" a hash, it's one way.  For "real" security, salt your hashes, or use a library like [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: Honesty I don't see a great improvement. If someone steal your database, he will understand your cropping method in a few seconds.

Comment: In other words: No, a cropped hash will not be more secure and should actually be substantially less secure. The only value would be making it _slightly_ more difficult for an attacker who "solved" your hash to use the results on another system. They would, however, be able to use the results just fine on _your_ system.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Collisions occur when two values result in this same hash. A good hashing function will typically have a very low rate of collisions but as your remove characters from the resulting hash you gradually increase the chances that you have removed what made that hash distinctive from another.

Comment: Aside from brute force attacks, are there any other concerns that collisions could rise?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: Regardless, cropping your hashes is a bad idea, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: why do you want to do this in the first place? elaborate!

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: I think everyone else already has.  It's a bad idea, as you're just removing security with no gain whatsoever.

Comment: I'm surprised at the downvote -- I thought this question was _very_ clearly asked. Please don't confuse voting on the quality of the question with whether the question is proposing a good idea or a bad idea...

Comment: Edit,  md5 is not a method of encryption and there for cannot be "decrypted"

Answer (score 7):

Take this idea to its extreme: assume you're storing only the *first* hex character of your hashed passwords.

*All* your users' passwords would hash into one of sixteen values:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I'll admit that it would be very difficult for [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to brute-force decode these passwords, but it would *also* let someone guess another user's password in about eight tries on average.

Ooops.

If anything, you should store *longer* hashes. [Salt well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) instead.

Comment: I understand that the approach is more prone to brute force attacks, but I'm not too worried about it. The hashes I would use would be at least 32 characters long and instead of base 16 they would be more like base 64.

Comment: Don't forget that there are an _infinite_ number of inputs that hash into any given 256-bit hash code _and_ an _infinite_ number of inputs that hash into any given 64-bit hash code. If your users pick passwords like "123abc" or "password" that appear in common password lists, it'll be just as easy to brute-force _guess_ the password either way.

Comment: @sarnold: Too bad there still isn't a cure for stupid users. I just make it as hard as possible for my users to be stupid by enforcing strong passwords.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I hope for the sake of your users that the passwords you force to be strong are more of the variety suggested by [`pwqgen`](http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/screenshots). :)

Comment: @sarnold Agreed! High-entropy passwords don't have to be so impossibly hard to remember that they end up on post-it notes or that the password recovery feature becomes the norm.

Answer (score 5):

A quick summary of what I posted in the comments above:

Cropping a hash will result in a greater likelihood of collisions. Collisions occur when two values result in the same hash. A good hashing function will typically have a very low rate of collisions but as you remove characters from the resulting hash you gradually increase the chances that you have removed what made that hash distinctive from another.

**In other words:** No, a cropped hash will not be more secure and will in fact be substantially less secure. The only value would be making it slightly more difficult for an attacker who "solved" your hash to use the results on another system. They would, however, be able to use the results just fine on your system.

Salting your hash, on the other hand, makes it less susceptible to rainbow tables and other methods of brute-force decoding while still keeping your collisions to a minimum.

**Also,** it should be noted that when you view cropping the hash as a password-protecting feature you are actually banking on the occurrence of collisions. I assume the only reason you are considering this at all is that you do not want an attacker to be able to use someone's password on another site, because obviously you do not benefit on your own. The fewer bits you remove the smaller the set of collisions and therefore the higher the likelihood that the attacker can still recover (or at least guess) the original password.

For example:

If the attacker finds that `a6shp` and `ghsa2` and `apple` all reduce to the same cropped hash then 1) they will have been able to log into *your* system the minute they encountered the first working result, but also 2) they will have a pretty good idea which result was actually the password. If you crop off so much data that literally tens of thousands of combinations would match then it becomes harder (but not *that much* harder) and yet the security of your own system is now substantially decreased. This goes on and on until the number of collisions nears infinity.

Answer (score 4):

Cropping your hashes is a REALLY BAD IDEA.

Consider the following two passwords:

```
password1
password2
```

With the following hashes:

```
732654732854235
732654732837454
```

Now let's crop those hashes to say 10 chars. Now we get:

```
7326547328
7326547328
```

Wow that sucks.

Now I can login with either password1 or password2.

If you are worried about a malicious user getting the database with your passwords just make sure you:

- used crypt
- used unique salts for every password

Comment: If your crops are longer (32 characters or even more) and instead of base 10 your hashes are in base 64, would you have that concern?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: It's unlikely with bigger strings, but why risk it?  Regardless, cropping your hashes is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Rocket, here are a few reasons: harder to decrypt, faster to look up, uses less memory.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: It doesn't matter what algo / digest / encoding / whatever you use. You are always making it less secure so why would you want that?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: You cannot "decrypt" a hash (you can crack it, and no, it doesn't make it harder, it makes it easier).  Also, unless your strings are 1000 characters long, don't worry about memory usage.  All you're doing is removing security and gaining nothing.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev I added a little bit to my answer above dealing with this. What you need to realize is that the only perceived benefit you could possibly receive is actually a direct bi-product of the number of collisions (and therefore reduced security).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear here how "cropping" hashes is defined, but I see 4  purposes in it:

1. Data storage. Every representation "cropped" saves storage thereof, while increasing collision said thereof.
2. Zero knowledge (of which-password). (Read: Staying silent at times when there's value in staying silent.) Verifier knows that:

   1. F`(`input`)` is hash
   2. F`(`answer`)` is hash
   3. F`(`wrong answer`)` isn't hash
   4. F`(`answer 2`)` is hash

   . But he doesn't know if input is answer or answer-2. (Read: don't bother posing as Verifier, or rubberhosing/courtordering Verifier to determine whether input is <attack at dawn>.  <attack at noon> hashes to the same result. Oh btw, <defend at dawn>, <defend at noon>, <sleep at dawn>, <sleep at noon> all hash to the same result.)
3. [btw this could be mis-used so I'm leaving it out]
4. [btw this could be mis-used so I'm leaving it out]